# Reasigning a listner variable to onSnapshot thows error

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase firestore to get a callback when a document changes. I am assigning this listener to a variable so that it can be detached. But when I reassign it, it throws an error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>       Error: "query1Listner" is read-only.

I understand that the listner firestore provides is immutable. But I am detaching the listner using

```
if (query1Listner != null) {
  query1Listner();
  query1Listner = null;
}
```

as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

```
query1Listner = myChatsQuery1.onSnapshot((data) => {
  let chatNodes = [];
  data.forEach(doc => {
    chatNodes.push(doc.data());
  });
  if (chatNodes && chatNodes.length > 0) {
    callback(chatNodes);
  }
}, errorCallback);
```

actual result listener should be able to reassign it to another snapshot but I am getting an error.